# How can I migrate my windows 10 to new hardware using sysprep?

Tags: windows-10, sysprep

So, my mainboard of my office pc is now dead (finally) and I have been given a new pc with better spec. I am trying to move my windows & all my applications along with it(which is still intact in my old pc HDD C: ). So far, I found we can `%windir%\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown` currently loaded windows and make it ready for new hardware. But, my situation is I can't boot my old pc any more. Is it possible we can plug in my old HDD into new pc and boot it with some live OS may be and apply this `sysprep` on my old HDD externally and prepare it for new pc?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to sysprep. You should literally be able to plug the old drive into the new machine and just boot it. Worst case, you need to manually install some drivers for the new hardware.

Comment: Nope Ryan! In my case my new pc with old hdd restarting continuously which is odd. One reason may be, because unfortunately I couldn't do a `sysprep` before my old pc finally died.